# Actionresult is fired on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a shopping application in **MVC 4** in which the user can add items to the cart and correspondingly the shopping cart gets displayed

```
    public ActionResult GetShoppingCart(int cartID)
    {
        ShoppingCartActions userShoppingcart = new ShoppingCartActions();
        userShoppingcart.AddToCart(cartID);
        return View(userShoppingcart.GetCartItems());

    }
```

However on page refresh this ActionResult is called again and duplicate entry is added.How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split this into a GET and POST request:

```
public ActionResult GetShoppingCart()
{
    ShoppingCartActions userShoppingcart = new ShoppingCartActions();
    return View(userShoppingcart.GetCartItems());
}

[HttPost]
public ActionResult GetShoppingCart(int cartID)
{
    ShoppingCartActions userShoppingcart = new ShoppingCartActions();
    userShoppingcart.AddToCart(cartID);
    return View(userShoppingcart.GetCartItems());

}
```

GET request should be idempotent, meaning, it should not alter any data. POST requests are for changing the resource's data.

Comment: I am calling it from <a href="@Url.Action("GetShoppingCart","Cart",new { cartID = item.ProductID })" how can i call post action ?

Comment: Stick it inside a `form` tag